# How can I extend the length of an ethernet cable?

Tags: networking

How can I extend the length of an ethernet cable? Are there repeaters for ethernet cables or should I go with fibre or something else?

I have the following problem, the network connectivity stops to work randomly after 2 or 3 weeks, at first the DHPC pool wasn't configured properly but I double checked and it's configured properly now, I've configured the DLAN AP to forward the dhcp queries to the router.

[image]

I have also tried to replace the HUB with a linksys switch but it's the same.
Any ideas what could cause it to stop working randomly?

Comment: How long is the cable? How long does it need to be? Which type of Ethernet is it (10Mbps, 100Mbps, GigE)? And what kind of cable is it (cat 5, cat 5e, cat 6)?

Comment: mh okay if it can be up to 100 meters then this can't be the problem because it's like 50 meters

Comment: Are you having trouble with a current cable? it could be damaged if you are.

Comment: yea... kindof, it keeps stopping to work randomly after about 2 or 3 weeks

Comment: Add these details in your question. Hardware too.

Comment: Sorry I can't provide the exact hardware speccs now because it's at a friends house and he just called me that it isn't working again.

Comment: What is weird is that it happens only every 2-3 weeks. The wireless clients have no problems? What about the PC directly connected to the hub? It could also be caused by a "bad" device - either the router or the hub. You could leave out the hub and connect the single PC directly with the 50 m cable and see if it still occurs.

Comment: Yea it's really weird, I borrowed him the linksys switch because of that because I suspected the hub to be the problem, he said he swapped it and it still didn't work.. I'm going to look at it now I'll report back later.

Comment: You don't maybe have a Ethernet cable tester on hand?  It could also be that one of the RJ45 connectors was not crimped properly.

Comment: @StBlade: It's weird though that it only happens from time to time.

Comment: Some random thoughts: <animal of choice> chewing on cable? Cable goes through behind a microwave (or other wave-emitting device) that used rarely and the cable got interference from that?

Comment: I thought the same because it's an old house, but after trying around I noticed that one port of the adapter had a loose contact, it was just a strange coincidence that it happened twice after 2-3 weeks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ethernet cables can be up to 100 m. If you want to go beyond that length, you need some active hardware in between. A simple solution would be a cheap hub/switch. A simple ethernet repeater would do as well, but they are usually aimed at enterprises and thus probably more expensive than a simple hub.

EDIT: I see you added a diagram now and you are already using a hub. So I am revoking this as an answer.

Comment: They are already using a HUB per their diagram. The only reason I won't issue a downvote is because the author changed their question to include a diagram only after your answer was submitted.

Comment: @Ramhound: Exactly that is what happend.

Comment: I partly agree. I understood it as a more general question towards extending ethernet segments, and not as a problem with a specific setup.

Comment: Looking at the original question (again), I suppose in retrospect, you answered actual question that was asked.  So I withdraw my secondary comment.

Comment: Yea well it was my initial question so I'll mark it as accepted answer, it was a loose contact after all. At first I thought maybe the cable is too long!